# Object class, java API

Tags: java, interface, queue, overriding, abstract

When I implement a Queue interface, it requires me to implement all abstract methods within that interface. However, some methods has an input variable of the type Object. what does it refer to, and is it possible to change it to a String type or any other primitive type in java? Because, for example, in this abstract method:

```js
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MyQueue implements Queue {
  
  @Override
    public boolean add(Object e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); /*Inserts the specified 
        element into this queue if it is possible to do so immediately without violating 
        capacity restrictions, returning true upon success and throwing an IllegalStateException
        if no space is currently available.
        */
    }
  
  }
```

When I start to implement this method to make my own Queue class with an input of String type instead of an Object type, it tells me to implement the original abstract method again! As you can see in the following snippest:

```
@Override
public boolean add(String name) {
    boolean result = true;

    if (rear == maxSize - 1) {
        result = false;
        throw new IllegalStateException("There is No Enough Space.");
    } else {
        names[++rear] = name;
        front = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queue<E>` is a *generic* interface. This means it has a *type parameter* `E`.

If you write

```
class MyQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {
    ...
}
```

then you will be required to override `add(E e)`, not `add(Object e)`. This is probably what you should write.

If you write

```
class MyStringQueue implements Queue<String> {
    ...
}
```

then you will be required to override `add(String e)`. This is what you should write if your implementation only works for `String`s.

If you just write

```
class MyQueue implements Queue {
    ...
}
```

then you will be forced to override `add(Object e)`. However you should not use the raw type `Queue` without a type parameter.

The easiest way to implement `Queue` is to make your class extend `AbstractQueue<E>` because then most of the hard work is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since String is extended from Object class you just have to override the methods with Object as input and then you can pass String while calling the function.

Comment: @fox as i showed in my sample, BUT you have to check type of object then if you don't wan't unpredictable behavior. If String is all you want and nothing else then pbabcdefp solution is the best

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `Queue<String>`, not just `Queue`, if you want to type the member objects. That takes care of the `add()` method and several others. However there are still some that must take `Object` for historical/compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Just give him what he wants! You can keep the original abstract signature.

```
public boolean add(Object e) {
    boolean result = true;

    // and now you can check by class name if you got a string
    if (e.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + e);
    } else {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can just use the e object like a string then, **BUT** you defiantly should check if you really got a string there, since the function would except anything now, ***HENCE***: use `e.getClass()` to check what kind of object you got.

Comment: actually if you **ONLY** want to handle strings and nothing else, then what pbabcdefp suggested with the `implements Queue<String>` is the preferable way to go